# win-bash won't detect root drives?

Tags: windows, path, bash-scripting

I'm using the windows port of bash known as win-bash, and based on what it says about paths:

> One important difference is the handling of drives: cygwin uses its
>   installation directory as root dir and links all drives in the pseudo
>   subdir /cygdrive. win-bash uses a diffent method: drives are included
>   in paths, like on windows (e.g. c:/Winnt/System32). The root directory
>   / is mapped to the root directory of the current drive. Examples: ls
>   c:/winnt - shows the content of the directory c:/winnt cd c:/; ls
>   /winnt - changes current drive to c: and shows the content of the
>   directory c:/winnt cd d:/; ls /winnt- changes current drive to d: and
>   shows the content of the directory d:/winnt There are some other
>   differences, most of them have been added to simplify the usage of
>   existing un*x shell scripts: If a shell script starts with an
>   interpreter specification like #!/path/interpreter, the interpreter is
>   searched in the PATH environment instead of /path. E.g. a Perl script
>   starting with #!/bin/perl will be started with perl.exe from the PATH
>   environment variable. win-bash doesn't use any dlls or registry keys

Detecting non-root paths seem to work such as:
`if [ -d "C:/bash" ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi` However, detecting root paths like so `if [ -d "C:/" ]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi` does not work. This also includes `C:` and `/`.

Perhaps there is another syntax bash scripting syntax to detect the existence of paths?

Comment: Do `C:/.` and `C:/bash/..` work?

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding a period after the root drive path works as suggested by ignis.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: do `C:/.` and `C:/bash/..` work?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to win-bash would be winbash from [here](http://winbash.tigris.org). It did a better job at detecting root paths. Both "C:/" and "/" return yes on the tests. Only "C:" failed.

Plus I like that winbash handles the familiar <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-key combos we're used to like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>, etc. (in win-bash it just returns "^P" on the screen).